# Filtering a resource in Jersey similar to @RequestMapping "Params" attribute of Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-2.0, request-mapping

I'm in the process of converting all my Spring Services to Jersey, when I came across an issue about how to convert the RequestParam's **params** feature of Spring to Jersey?

@RequestMapping(value = "/earnings", **params = "type=csv"**)

Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/earnings", params = "type=csv")
public void earningsCSV() {}

@RequestMapping(value = "/earnings", params = "type=excel")
public void earningsExcel() {}

@RequestMapping("/earnings")
public void earningsSimple() {}
```

Jersey:

```
@Path("/earnings") 
public void earningsCSV() {}

@Path("/earnings")
public void earningsExcel() {}

@RequestMapping("/earnings")
public void earningsSimple() {}
```

How to specify the type "csv/excel" in Jersey?
**Does Jersey even support Filtering Requests based on Param's?**

If not, is there any way I can achieve this?
I was thinking of a filter which process them and re-directs requests, but I've nearly 70+ services which needs to be addressed this way. 
So I'll have to end up writing a filter for all of them. Also, It doesn't sound like a clean approach.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no configuration in Jersey to define this, the way its done in spring.

I solved this by creating a Parent Service which accepts the call and re-directs the call to respective services based on param.

```
@Path("/earnings")
public void earningsParent(@QueryParam("type") final String type) {
    if("csv".equals(type)) 
         return earningsCSV();
    else if("excel".equals(type)) 
         return earningsExcel();
    else 
         return earningsSimple();
}

public void earningsCSV() {}

public void earningsExcel() {}

public void earningsSimple() {}
```

I felt this approach was better than Filter as it doesn't need the developer to go change the Filter in future if it needs to be extended.